# Blogger - How to view page hits statistics

Tags: blogger

Is there a way to view the page hits statistics in in your blog on Bogger (http://www.blogger.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you are logged in, either click "Design" in the upper right, then click "stats" tab, or "Dashboard", click "stats".  You can drill down into stats about the blog, page, post, etc. for different time periods.

Comment: It's been a few days. Curious to see if this answered your question - or were you looking for a particular stat?

Answer (score 0):

Just go on the "Design" link and if you dont want that, just try different tools like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) which is free and you can easily use that to see

- How many page views you are getting,
- How many searched visitors and
- How many referred visitors